# WPF Binding keeps changing already added Items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What I'm trying to do is,
I have a class named Ferramenta that should hold a list of type Atividades so I can keep adding Atividades to the given Ferramenta.
But I'm having trouble as I can add one Atividade just fine, but if I go and change any TextBox input it automatically changes the atividade that's inside the Atividades List which doesn't make sense because it's supposed to be a whole different scope.

*I can see its changing the same one as I type because I have a DataGrid displaying the content.*

**XAML:**

```
                    <TextBox Margin="{StaticResource ControlMargin}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MetroButtonTextBox}" 
                    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm},Path=atividade.Responsavel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                          />
                    <DatePicker
                    Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Selecione uma data"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm},Path=atividade.DateInicio,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                    <DatePicker
                       Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Selecione uma data"
                       SelectedDate="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm},Path=atividade.DateTermino,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                    <Button Width="40"
                        Height="40"
                        Margin="20"
                        Style="{StaticResource AccentCircleButtonStyle}"
                        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm},Path=addAtividade}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=atividade}">
                    </Button>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public AdicionarAtividade addAtividade { get; set; }
public Atividade atividade { get; set; }
public Ferramenta ferramenta { get; set; }

public ConsultaAtividadesViewModel(){
    ferramenta = new Ferramenta()
    {
        OrdemServico = "12345", //Debugging purposes
        SFerramenta = "123456",//Debugging purposes
        Peca = "12345",//Debugging purposes
        Atividades = new ObservableCollection<Atividade>()
    };
    addAtividade = new AdicionarAtividade(this);
    atividade = new Atividade();
}
```

**What matters on the class Ferramenta**

```
    class Ferramenta : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Atividade> atividades;
    public ObservableCollection<Atividade> Atividades
    {
        get { return atividades; }
        set { atividades = value; OnPropertyChanged("Atividades"); } //I think the problem is here on the setter

    }
```

**The register command**

```
        ConsultaAtividadesViewModel vm { get; set; } //The View viewModel
    public AdicionarAtividade(ConsultaAtividadesViewModel vm)
    {
        this.vm = vm;
    }
    //CanExecute stripped out for making it easier to understand
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        vm.ferramenta.Atividades.Add(parameter as Atividade);
    }
```

Also I don't know if it's worth adding but my idea was, in the XAML I make it change an already set Atividade item according to what the user types then once he presses the register the args from the Atividade at the ViewModel gets passed to the command which then adds it to the List, "breaking" the bound.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the Atividade constructor to take in an Atividade as parameter and set its variables and changed the execute to

```
        vm.ferramenta.Atividades.Add(new Atividade((Atividade)parameter));
```